# Error code 406 when I use dot Net MS Graph SDK to get myself's user info?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-sdks

Here is my code,basically all of it is copied from Microsoft document sample code:

```
private async static void exec()
{
    try
    {
        var clientId = "soemid here";
        var tenantID = "some id here";

        string[] scopes = new string[] { "User.Read"};
        
        var email = "xxxx@xx.com";
        System.Security.SecureString password = new System.Security.SecureString();
        password.AppendChar('x');
        ... 
        // append whole password here
        password.AppendChar('x');

        IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
         .Create(clientId)
         .WithTenantId(tenantID)
         .Build();

        UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);

        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
           
        User me = await graphClient.Me.Request()
                        .WithUsernamePassword(email, password)
                        .GetAsync();

        Console.WriteLine(me.Id);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This issue is nothing is printed instead I'm receiving a 406 error code.  How can I fix it?
By the way in the documentation of Microsoft 406 means **This service doesn’t support the format requested in the Accept header.**

Comment: Try a different version of the Microsoft.Graph.Auth package. If that solves it consider submitting an issue. Incidentally, you should not write void async methods.

Comment: @Crowcoder Thanks for reply.I tried several other versions of  Microsoft.Graph.Auth package,still same error code every time I tried. I think there is something wrong in my code....By the way,I am using  **Microsoft.Graph.Beta -Version 0.19.0-preview** instaead of Microsoft.Graph package.Because I intend to using api under the beta directory.Will that be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this problem, I test it in my side with the same version of `Microsoft.Graph`(Microsoft.Graph.Beta -Version 0.19.0-preview) with you. But it works fine in my side, so I provide my code below for your reference.

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Security;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp22
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            var clientId = "xxx";
            var tenantID = "xxx";

            string[] scopes = new string[] { "User.Read" };
            var email = "xxx";
            
            var str = "xxx";
            var password = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in str) password.AppendChar(c);

            IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                 .Create(clientId)
                 .WithTenantId(tenantID)
                 .Build();

            UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            User me = await graphClient.Me.Request()
                                .WithUsernamePassword(email, password)
                                .GetAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(me.Id + "===" + me.DisplayName);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

For your issue, could you please create a new project and install the same packages with me in the screenshot above, and then try it again.

By the way, I ran the code with .net core 3.1

=======================**Update**======================

If you can't make your `main` method async, you can write the code as below:

[image]

Or if your execution code is in another class, you can write the code as:

[image]

Comment: I ran my code with .Net Framwork 4.6.1.Right now I am in the middle of something,so I really can't try your code out for a while.But still thanks very much.

Comment: @Xia Take your time, and if you have any problem when you test the code, please let me know.

Comment: Hi @Xia May Did you get a chance to look into this ? If it works fine, could you please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Comment: I try your code today,still error code 406.I can't make my ```main``` async,so I change code as this: ```User me = await graphClient.Me.Request()
.WithUsernamePassword(email, password).GetAsync().Result;```

Comment: @Xia So have you solved the problem after change the code `User me.....GetAsync().Result;` ?

Comment: still the same error code.I tried another sample on here:[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-windows-desktop),which use ```AcquireTokenInteractive``` api.This new sample works just fine for me.But I perfer to use ```graphClient.Me.Request() .WithUsernamePassword``` api.

Comment: @Xia Please refer to the "Update" in my answer.

Comment: I wonder if there is something wrong about  my config of app on https://portal.azure.com/ .I set a reply URL on azure app,but it seems like unnecessary cause my code don't refer it.

Comment: @Xia I don't think it has anything to do with reply url. Please test with my latest code, if still have problem, let me know.

Comment: I'd like to try your new code,but I can't open your picture link.....Something went wrong about Stackoverflow I guess.

Comment: @Xia It may be caused by your network setting, please check your network and then you can see the picture.

Comment: I fix my network now and try your code. still same error code 406.I am so confused.I guess I can't use ```WithUsernamePassword``` for some reason.

Comment: @Xia Did you change the code from .net framework 4.6.1 to .net core ?

Comment: It seems like .Net core 3.1 don't support Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: @Xia I do all of the job in visual studio 2019

Comment: I change my account from a personal account to a work account,and register a new app under the work tenent on azure.Now I can get account info in .Net Framework4.6.1.I don't konw why I can't use personal account but anyway my code is runnable now,so this is it.I will continue develop and thanks for your help.